# Override browser spellchecking with your own?

Tags: javascript, html, spell-checking

I'm writing a form with javascript validation, I'd like to override the browser's built in spell checking.

For example, let's say I'm checking serial numbers and they all pass a regex text. I'd like to highlight the ones who don't in the browser much likes the browser highlights words with invalid spelling.

All I could come up with is disabling the browser's built in spell checking

**So to sum it up**

Is there a simple way to override a browser's built in spell check (sort of how like you override the comparator when you sort an array in javascript)

If there is not, is there a simple way to emulate such behavior?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I was really hoping that this was a thing.  @HTML5 make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer; no, there is no Spellcheck API that JavaScript can hook into. Besides these kinda seem like different goals; a spellcheck is about natural language whereas you seem to really want input validation. You'd be better simply applying a different background / border colour or similar hint to the user via CSS when your JavaScript code detects an invalid serial (especially since each browser will render spellcheck errors differently anyway).

Comment: Thanks. Still it seems kind of odd they would let you turn it off but not override it in any way. Wspecially since you can pretty much override anything in javascript. I guess emulating it by coloring the form data myself will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't evaluated the code, but CkEditor manages to disable browser spell checking. It has a config setting that's set to true by default: [disableNativeSpellChecker](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.disableNativeSpellChecker)

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = true;
```

The setting is used within the "wysiwygarea" plugin, here's a link to the plugin code: [wysiwygarea plugin](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/plugins_wysiwygarea_plugin.js.html)

Maybe you can use it as a basis for your own code to disable browser spell checking.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the demo from the Url below, it think it might be helpful in your case although it works just with HTML5.

http://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/ZU74B/

Here is the code they used in the demo:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var support = document.getElementById("support");

    if('spellcheck' in document.createElement('textarea'))
    {
        support.textContent = "Your browser supports spellcheck";
        support.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't see how that helps me though. You're suggesting a method to _detect_ spellcheck and I'm looking for a way to _override_ it.